# Uploaded file safety: banning file archives

Tags: php, zip, mime-types

I want to verify uploaded file types in PHP and restrict uploads to relatively safe type.

My web app allows for online reporting of academic dishonesty (usually plagiarism).  The use can upload supporting documentation.  The report gets emailed to the appropriate college officials with supporting files as documentation as attachments.  I am trying to protect the email recipients as much as reasonably possible from dangerous attachments.

Since the email recipients are all college addresses, all the emails get run through a malware checker before being delivered.  However, I'd like to do at least check for dangerous file types.

At least the first check is with php finfo_file or finfo::file.  However, it will call some files that are not used as zips are really zips anyway. MS Office files are examples.  This is a problem in that File archives such as zip, gzip, etc. are dangerous because they can hide dangerous files.  I can't simply use finfo::file ban zip files without banning, for example, docx files which I need not to ban.  Not that docx files are particularly safe, I need to allow them anyway.

I could check the file extension to see if the extension declares it to be a file archive.  How many of those extensions are there? Ugh.  Or, I could whitelist a few types.  Or, ....

Surely this is not a new issue.  Is there a best practice here?  Failing that, are do people have suggestions for reasonable checks/rules to implement?

Comment: First of all; I would never send them as attachment. I'd just store them online and have them viewed by logging in or using a special link.

Comment: That (storing and sending by a link) would ideally be better.  But the good file type filtering issue still remains.